# Openshift plone quickstart permission denied

Tags: git, ssh, plone, openshift

I'm trying to set up plone on openshift using [this](https://github.com/kagesenshi/plone-openshift-quickstart) guide, on windows.  I've got git and rhc following the [openshift quickstart guide](https://www.openshift.com/get-started).  However, when I get to `git pull -s recursive -X theirs upstream master` in the plone guide, I get a permission denied error:

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.252.130)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.252.130' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but I did add the ssh key during `rhc setup`.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I needed to set up my public key in github too.  Once I configured git and github it worked.  For anyone else encountering this problem, here's what I did:

1. Added the same public key used in openshift to github [here](https://github.com/settings/ssh) (obviously needed to login first)
2. Set up my name and email in git using `git config --global user.name "My Name"` and `git config --global user.email "my@email.com"`

I don't know git, github or ssh well enough to understand why it was necessary to log into github first, but it worked.  I hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is: Use the https url instead of the ssh url.

I.e.: Use `https://github.com/kagesenshi/plone-openshift-quickstart.git` instead of `git@github.com:kagesenshi/plone-openshift-quickstart.git`