# SSH "Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts" Openshift

Tags: authentication, ssh, key, openshift

I tried to use `ssh` command to connect to another remote host.

```
ssh -p 21098 -i $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/.ssh/host_key user@domain.com   

The authenticity of host '[domain.com]:21098 ([124.219.148.93]:21098)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 12:15:79:55:c6:2a:66:1e:82:94:da:19:e1:ca:21:3d.

Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/var/lib/openshift/541b685c5973cae7bbf006f4/.ssh/known_hosts).

Connection closed by 124.219.148.93
```

I suppose we do not have access to `home/.ssh`. So how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can pass options to SSH on command line, like this:

`ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/tmp/known_host_file -p 21098 -i $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/.ssh/host_key user@domain.com`

Here is related answer: [ssh use known_hosts other than $HOME/.ssh/known_hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765946/ssh-use-known-hosts-other-than-home-ssh-known-hosts)

Comment: This answer is correct and it is helpful to eliminate the error and clarify the issue; however, it is not the reason that the connection closed. For example, my problem is permission of ./ssh/authorized.key in the remote site is not correct.